# Question about sum of primes

Tags: prime-numbers

Let $P(x)$ be the xth prime, $P(0)=2$

Given a prime $p$, does it always exists a $n$ such $\sum_{x=0}^{n}P(x) = 0$ $(mod$  $p)$ ?

Example :

$p=7$

$2+3+5+7+11=28=4*7$

Best regards

Comment: i have an another question :  is there well known  universal formula for generation of prime numbers? if not than this question seems  unanswerable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://oeis.org/A111287 is smallest $k$ such that $p_n$ divides $\sum_{i=1}^kp_i$.  It says, "It follows from a theorem of Daniel Shiu that $k$ always exists," and many more details are given. [And I'm pretty sure I have already seen, maybe even posted, this answer to m.se before]

EDIT: I found the earlier question, [Every prime number divide some sum of the first $k$ primes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882613/every-prime-number-divide-some-sum-of-the-first-k-primes) and have voted to close this one as a duplicate.